# Sql Server 2008 MERGE like operation, but acting on different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been using the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) operation in SQL Server 2008, but have now come across a similar scenario where I need the same "detection" behaviour (`WHEN MATCHED`, `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`, `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`), but want the resulting operations to be on different tables, not the source or the target.

In other words, I have two result-sets, `beforeTable` and `afterTable` and I want to do something along the lines of:

```
MERGE afterTable AS dest
USING beforeTable AS source 
ON (dest.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    --INSERT tblModifiedItems (ID) VALUES (ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    --INSERT tblRemovedItems (ID) VALUES (ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    --INSERT tblAddedItems (ID) VALUES (ID)
```

Presently I do this with three seperate (albeit very simple) queries across the two tables, but the MERGE approach would allow it to be done as a single operation. I just can't see whether it can be used to target different tables than the two under comparison.

Is this possible, and if so how?

**[EDIT]**

The reason I want to do this is not due to issues around atomicity of the INSERTS into added/removed/modifed (the whole thing is already in a transaction). It is because I want to be able to generate the three sets of data in a single query, or at least a single *statement* which also makes the intent very clear.

Comment: MERGE, as with the other DML ops (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) can only affect one table (although other tables can be used for obtaining values, filtering, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer would be: no, you can't. MERGE is an operation between source table and destination table and that's it. But, I suggest an work-around (there is always one). You'll have to write some more code, but it will do the trick.

Do this:

```
DECLARE @AuxTable table(    
    id int,
    OLD_name varchar(50),
    new_name varchar(50)
    )

merge table2 as dest
using table1 as src
on (dest.id=src.id)
when not matched by target then
  insert (id, name) values (src.id, src.name)
when matched then
  UPDATE SET dest.NAME=src.name
when not matched by SOURCE then
   DELETE

  output inserted.id, DELETED.name, INSERTED.NAME
  into @AuxTable
  ;

  select * from @AuxTable
```

see the `"output into @AuxTable"`? That will insert all the modified values by your merge on a temp table. What yo'll have to do is run through this table and build a string to execute the SQL on your other table.

Use this logic:

- WHEN OLD_NAME = NULL -> INSERT
- WHEN OLD_NAME != NEW_NAME -> UPDATE
- WHEN NEW_NAME = NULL -> DELETE

Comment: From what I can see - this won't actually solve the problem. Unless I've misunderstood it, "output" can only appear at the end of the whole MERGE statement (not in the individual cases) and will write all the records out to a third table, but won't let me mark the records as to whether they were matched, not matched in source, etc. So it doesn't get me any further - unless I've misunderstood the usage of output.

Comment: OK - I see what you mean - although I'd need to have a column that was not nullable. Next part of the question on your solution. I don't actually want to do any operations in the matched/not matched/etc cases _other_ than to build up this list of added/remove/modified. I don't really want to amend the destination table at all - just build up a summary of changes between src and dest. Can I use output like you have indicated, without actual operations on the dest table?

Comment: sure, just add a begin transaction before the query and a rollback in the end. Table Variables don't participate on transactions so you will have the result of what "would have happened" in your Auxtable, without that actually happening. Talking of work-arounds... :)

Comment: The trouble then is that I am actually doing the _work_ of the inserts, updates and deletes - only to then roll it back. I think your solution is a pretty good creative set of workarounds, but overall I suspect I am trying to misuse the MERGE command a bit too much!

Comment: yes you are right, it a big data set it would be a problem because you would face all the issue of actually performing the operations (lock, resources usage, etc..). But, I told you since the beginning that this is not the use for MERGE. This solution would be semi-perfect if you actually needed to perform the operation instead of generating a report of "what would happen if..."

Comment: Marking as correct for "short answer would be: no, you can't. "